# Private static member in base class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, g++, static-members

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Base
{
    static std::string s;
};

template<typename T>
class Derived
    : Base
{
public:
    Derived()
    {
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
    }
};

std::string Base::s = "some_text";    

int main()
{
    Derived<int> obj;
}
```

This programs compiles and runs normally. static variable `s` is private in base class that is inherited privately. How is Derived class accessing it?

If Derived class is not template, compiler complains about accessing private variable.

```
[aminasya@amy-aminasya-lnx c++]$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: Which compiler? gcc, clang?

Comment: Reading this question, could someone explain why the compiler doesn't think the line 'std::string Base::s = "some_text";' is global access, so prohibited for a private variable? Has been some time since I used C++.

Comment: That's a definition, not a declaration. It's just initializing the string that was previous declared inside of Base; since it was declared inside Base it is a class static variable, and it is private since that is the default access level for class.

Comment: I think this is a compiler bug, as this compiles with gcc but not clang, for me.

Comment: GCC bug, clang and ICC reject this code. Note that GCC has many bugs when it comes to access specification control and templates...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is definitely a GCC bug, equivalent to [GCC Bug 58740](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58740):

```
class A {
    static int p;
};
int A::p = 0;
template<int=0>
struct B : A {
    B() {(void)p;}
};
int main() {
    B<>();
}
```

The bug is still open, and this code still compiles on 5.1. GCC has issues with template member access, this is just another such example.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is a compiler bug, as this compiles with gcc but not clang, for me.

Edit: as an additional data point, this bug does not seem to have been fixed, as I can reproduce in gcc 4.9.2 and 5.1.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bug in g++ 4.8.4. The code compiles, only if `Derived` is a template and the member is static.

Tests:

- template     static      compiles
- no template  static      fails
- template     not static  fails
- no template  not static  fails